# Регулярное выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пропустил изучение регулярных выражений, а в задаче нужно сделать на php проверку, чтобы человек мог ввести время и минуты, максимум 99 часов и 59 минут, вид такой 99:59.

Пробовал так, но не выходит. `/^([01][0-9]|2[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/`
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$re = '/([0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/';
$str = '99:59';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```